# How can I convert this JQuery into vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello there i have been trying for the last few day to convert all my jquery into vanilla javascript and this is one of the few that i am having the problems with

```
 $(".book").click(function(){
    var timeslot = $(this).attr('data-timeslot');
    $("#slot").html(timeslot);
    $("#timeslot").val(timeslot);

})
```

this is what i have come up with so far and dont even know if i have started converting this correctly

```
var book = document.querySelector(".book");
book.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var timeslot = book.getAttribute('data-timeslot');
  document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML = timeslot;


}());
```

question is am i along the right lines or am heading the wrong direction

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: basically am i along the right lines

Comment: Yes. You have a opening and closing parentheses that are useless at the end `}());` but other than that i'd say you're one the right track

Comment: Depending on your Ecmascript version, i would like `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 1):

it is almost correct, except select should take all matches

```
var books = document.querySelectorAll(".book");
[...books].forEach(book => {
   book.addEventListener('click', function() {

   var timeslot = book.getAttribute('data-timeslot');
   document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML = timeslot;
  });
})
```

Comment: see with that i gett this error books.foreEach is not a function

Comment: `QuerySelectorAll` does not returns an array, it returns an [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Therefore you need to use the `Array.from` function in order to use the `forEach` function on it.

Comment: ah yes, might be that. I will update my answer. but it seems to work on chrome

Comment: I think forEach is not applicable after document.querySelectorAll on certain browsers so I spread the result to make sure it is in array format

Comment: @ducmai sorry i dont have a codeandbox link i just tried to use it and my code dont work in there at all

Comment: try again with my latest code, it should work I think

Comment: nope sorry i have tried and i just got a this is not a function error i can give a direct web address with my codes sorry code and box does not like php

Answer (score 0):

```js
var books = document.getElementsByClassName("book");
books.forEach( function(book) {
   book.addEventListener('click', function() {

   var timeslot = book.getAttribute('data-timeslot');
   document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML = timeslot;

  });
});
```

Comment: foreEach is not a valid method. try forEach